# NextJS & SVGR loading SVG as component breaks SVG

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js, svg-react-loader

```
"dependencies": {
    "daisyui": "^2.46.0",
    "next": "13.0.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.5.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.5"
```

The SVG's worked last night, now today fails to load. Nothing was changed within that time. SVG still renders in "SVG Viewer" websites. Assuming this is an SVGR issue.

[Broken Photo picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJPCO.png)

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig

module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    })
    return config
  },
};
```

Example code

```
import JavaScript from "../public/javascript.svg";

<div className="tooltip" data-tip="JavaScript">
<Image src={JavaScript} alt="JavaScript" height={50} width={50} className=""></Image>
</div>
```

SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg  fill="stroke" viewBox="100 100 375 375" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <title />
    <path 
   
        d="M32,32V480H480V32ZM272,380c0,43.61-25.76,64.87-63.05,64.87-33.68,0-53.23-17.44-63.15-38.49h0l34.28-20.75c6.61,11.73,11.63,21.65,26.06,21.65,12,0,21.86-5.41,21.86-26.46V240h44Zm99.35,63.87c-39.09,0-64.35-17.64-76.68-42h0L329,382c9,14.74,20.75,24.56,41.5,24.56,17.44,0,27.57-7.72,27.57-19.75,0-14.43-10.43-19.54-29.68-28l-10.52-4.52c-30.38-12.92-50.52-29.16-50.52-63.45,0-31.57,24.05-54.63,61.64-54.63,26.77,0,46,8.32,59.85,32.68L396,290c-7.22-12.93-15-18-27.06-18-12.33,0-20.15,7.82-20.15,18,0,12.63,7.82,17.74,25.86,25.56l10.52,4.51c35.79,15.34,55.94,31,55.94,66.16C441.12,424.13,411.35,443.87,371.35,443.87Z" />

</svg>
```

Console Error Code

```
Image is missing required "src" property: <img alt=​"JavaScript" src width=​"50" height=​"50" decoding=​"async" data-nimg=​"1" class loading=​"lazy" style=​"color:​transparent">​
window.console.error @ next-dev.js?3515:20
```

Attempted all the high liked posts within SVGR Github

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/26130

I've also attempted moving the @svgr/webpack npm package to dependencies instead of devDependencies to see maybe if it's a runtime issue but it didn't effect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a svgr issue. When you add svgr to your webpack config, this is overwrite nextjs *statically imported* behavior. Normally in the nextjs, the import result is like

```
{ src: string, width?: number, height?: number }
```

but when svgr is included, the import result turns into a react component.